# Non-public API usage error for my react-native app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store, webrtc

When i submit my react native app to appstore, it gets denied with the error:

> The app references non-public selectors in yourApp: channelId,
>   initWithURLStrings:, isBinary, reportId, sdp, sendData:,
>   setChannelId:, stringForType:, typeForString:

When i search my project, it looks like [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc) is using them, which is a npm module.

Did anyone faced this problem because of the used modules, and what should i do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to post an issue on the GitHub issues page of the submodule you've mentioned. If they're using non-public APIs they may need to make some changes.