# ios app using react-native-webrtc got rejected because of non-public api

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc

I'm using this library for my mobile app : https://github.com/react-native-webrtc

When I try to upload AppStore, they send me this email about Non-public API usage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CuYp.jpg

> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
>   delivery for your app, "BMHH" 1.0 (6). Please correct the following
>   issues, then upload again.   ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The
>   app references non-public selectors in Dating: addStream:, channelId,
>   initWithURLStrings:, isBinary, removeValuesForKeys:completion:, sdp,
>   sendData:, setChannelId:, setIsEnabled:, stringForType:,
>   typeForString:, videoSource. If method names in your source code match
>   the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will
>   help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In
>   addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a
>   static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be
>   removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support
>   Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

The author of library said he can upload the app without any problem : https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/615

Does anyone has the same problem ? How to fix it ?

thank you

Comment: This question [was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42784983/192373)

Comment: See also https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+non-public

Comment: As I mentioned, "The author of library said he can upload the app without any problem : https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/615" , it's not my solution

Comment: Could the difference be that the author's app is opensource?